# Is there a variant of Matlab structs that does not enforce the order of the fields?

Tags: matlab, struct

I want to add data to an array of structs without the fields of the added structs necessarily having the same *order* as the fields of the original structs. 
For example:

```
% Works fine:
students.name = 'John';
students.age = 28;
student2.name = 'Steve';
student2.age = 23;

students(2) = student2;

% Error if the order of the fields of student2 is reversed
students.name = 'John';
students.age = 28;
student2.age = 23;
student2.name = 'Steve';


students(2) = student2; % Error: Dissimilar structs
```

Is there a variant of struct I can add data to without having to keep the same order of fields?

EDIT: One workaround would be to always use matlabs "orderfields", which orders fields alphabetically. That is, the above erroneous example would become:

```
% Order fields alphabetically
students.name = 'John';
students.age = 28;
student2.age = 23;
student2.name = 'Steve';
students = orderfields(students);
student2 = orderfields(student2);
students(2) = student2; % Works
```

I am not sure whether this is the most natural solution.

Comment: probably applying `orderfields` to both structs fixes this.

Comment: Thanks, I saw your comment too late!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "natural" solution would be to **initiallize (create) each struct with a fixed order of fields**. Once the struct has been created this way, you can fill its fields in any order.

Also, you could **encapsulate the creation in a function**. This simplifies code and assures order is consistent. In your case, the creator function could be

```
create_student = @(x) struct('name',[], 'age',[]); %// empty fields. Fixed order
```

So your code would become

```
students = create_student(); %// call struct creator
students.name = 'John';
students.age = 28;
student2 = create_student(); %// call struct creator
student2.age = 23;
student2.name = 'Steve';
students(2) = student2; %// Now this works
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an alternative, that is using classes. See the documentation of [`classdef`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/classdef.html) for example, or more generally the [start page of Matlab's OOP](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html). Note that it requires from you to write some class files before using them, so it does not be as straightforward as using structs, but it's way more flexible once the class def job is done.

Comment: Thanks - good idea, but I think it's not very practical in my case!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to apply `orderfields` before you assign any struct, as Daniel suggests in the comments

```
>> students(1) = orderfields(struct('name', 'John', 'age', 18));
>> students(2) = orderfields(struct('age', 20, 'name', 'Jane'));
```